# Cache data when inserting in database and retrieve from cache through different getter methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I am new to spring boot and am trying to implement caching in my application.I am trying to cache the response when I insert a new object into the database and am trying to hit the cache when I call different get methods on the object.
What I'm trying to achieve is that when data is inserted ,it is cached and when I call methods like getattributesbyuserid or getattributesbyaddress,the data should be returned by cache.I tried using keys too but couldn't figure out what keys to use. I've been at this for few days and really need your help.Thanks in advance

```
@Transactional
public interface LocalRepositoryCustom {
//fetching
@Query("Select IdAttributes from Model IdAttributes where IdAttributes.userId= :userId")
@Cacheable(value="idatt")
List<Model > getIdAttributesForGivenuserID(@Param("userId") String userId);

@Query("Select IdAttributes from Model IdAttributes where IdAttributes.address= :address")
@Cacheable(value="idatt")
List<Model> IdAttributesForGivenAddress(@Param("address") String address);}
```

Controller:

```
List<Model> s=new ArrayList<Model>();@Autowired
private LocalRepository localservice;
@RequestMapping("/list/{userId}/{address}")
    @ResponseBody
    @CacheEvict(value="idatt",allEntries = true,beforeInvocation = true)
    @CachePut(value="idatt")
    public List<Model> add(@PathVariable String userId, @PathVariable String address) {


        Model newuser = new Model();

        newuser.setMoId(userId);
        newuser.setLocalIdString(address);


        localservice.save(newuser);
        s.add(newuser);
        return s;
```

}

Comment: Don't ask the same question over and over. There have been comments on why this doesn't work in your situation and what you should actually be doing. Trying to get a different answer by asking the same question every 5 days (in different forms) isn't going to give you a different answer/comment.

Comment: Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: You suggested using second level cache but I don't know how will that solve my issue.

Comment: Your `add` method uses two parameters for the cache key and the other methods use only one parameter, so that's one problem you have. It's most likely doable, but you'll have to write custom code to link the cache items together.

Comment: Yeah I tried using a custom key generator but then both the getters give the same response irrespective of the userId or address passed.I think this is because I'm caching the list and the whole list is returned by the getters.I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Sounds like your custom key generator wasn't correct then. Besides, you'll need to add 2 cache entries, for both keys. That's probably not possible with `key` or `keyGenerator`.

Comment: So what can I do then?Also I'm caching a the whole list  so I think there's a issue there too.

Comment: The cache doesn't care if you're caching a single object or a list. It takes an `Object` and is happy. You could get the cache programmatically and add the list manually for both keys.

Comment: can you give me an example please.I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: This article has a nice explanation on some normal caching operations, including one that caches the same value under two keys (with `@Caching` annotation): https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks

Comment: I've read this article.My issue is that I have to return a list since my getters have a list.So to cache both the methods with the same key,there return type should be same.Also since there could be multiple entries for each address or userid ,I need a list.Even if I use different keys for caching ,the save method caches the whole list which means both the getter methods give the same response when invoked.

Comment: Ah yeah. Well, then you need to get the cache from the `CacheManager` and manually update the lists saved for the keys. Something like `cacheManager.getCache("idatt").get(userId);`. I'd use a `Set` instead of `List` too.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you but I'm very new to this and it would be great if you could give me an example.

Comment: @Kayaman can you give me that method code please.Sorry to bother you but I can't figure out how to write it.

Comment: Also why should I use set instead of a list?

Comment: Because I doubt you want to have the same element twice in there, or does the order matter? I don't have any code for you, and frankly someone who is trying to write caching code needs to know the difference between a `List` and a `Set`. I've given you suggestions on what to do (like getting the cache from the cachemanager), but I don't have the time or the will to give you a full solution.

Comment: Oh ok no problem.Thanks for all the help man.

Comment: But If you can give me the solution that would be very kind of you.

Comment: Also using a set makes no difference as the constraints on my table make sure no duplicate elements are there as one field is always unique.

Comment: The table may not have duplicates, but if you use a `List`, your cache will allow duplicates in it.

Comment: Oh yes, good point.I'll use a set.Anyways the order doesn't matter so set would be appropriate.

Comment: If you could give me the solution I would be very grateful.